# Redirecting folders for a single program

Tags: windows

Is there a program or a trick/hack possibly that would let me create a virtual environment for a single program on Windows?

Let's say there's a program that accesses folders C:/foo and %appdata%/Roaming/bar. I cannot have these folders created so I have them in a different location, let's say D:/foo and D:/bar. Now, that program should think it accesses C:/foo and %appdata%/Roaming/bar but in reality it accesses folders D:/foo and D:/bar, so there's a transparent redirection going on.

Requirements:

1. Does not make changes to C:/foo and %appdata%/Roaming/bar (no symbolic links, etc.)
2. Redirection is only applied to a single selected program/EXE.
3. Virtual machines are out of the question.

I hope you know what I'm asking for :p

Comment: Please provide more information about why you need this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) to create a directory junction for source directory.
With [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx), every program will think it is accessing the source directory while in reality it is just a link to the destination directory.

Use this:

```
mklink /J C:\foo D:\bar
```

This makes programs think they are accessing the C:\foo but in reality it will be D:\bar

Comment: But will that work for all programs or just one program?

Comment: That will work for all programs. Even if you try to save a file into to C:\foo it will go into D:\bar

Comment: See the requirements in my edited post ;)